# How to send an email automatically to user when we enter them in DE

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

We want to send an email automatically to users when we enter them in DE.

We tried to do it using triggered send but unable to do like how and where should we write the logic.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to do the API calls"? Do you mean, making API calls using your current tech stack is not possible, or that the API calls that you tried failed? It's going to be challenging to give a recommendation if API calls are off the table.

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) tag.  Folks over there will need more details in order to help -- like what you've tried, where you're stuck, etc.